# How to check string has number as well as two special char only

Tags: regex, c#-4.0

I want result true if string has number with .(dot) or -(hyphen-minus) only otherwise false.

I can check number only by `Regex.IsMatch(input, @"^\d+$")` but I want to check .(dot) and -(hyphen-minus)

Expected O/p:

```
 Regex.IsMatch(input, @"^[\d-\.]+$")
   //this code works for below conditions only
    if string v1="10-20-30";  //true
    if string v1="10-20";  //true
    if string v1="10.20";  //true
    if string v1="10R20";  //false
    if string v1="10@20";  //false
    if string v1="10-20.30.40-50";  //true
    if string v1="10";  //true

    code not works for below conditions
    if string v1="10--20.30"; //false
    if string v1="10-20-30..";  //false
    if string v1="--10-20.30";  //false
    if string v1="-10-20.30";  //false
    if string v1="10-20.30.";  //false
```

Comment: Your second and third examples seems to indicate either `.` or `-` is ok and you do not require both. Is that correct?

Comment: You also do not mention the case there is neither `.` nor `-`.

Comment: How many separate numbers should there be?

Comment: yes, not necessary . or - are present. it may be possible there will be number only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can give a set of chars for match

```
Regex.IsMatch(input, @"^[\d-\.]+$")
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the given `True/False` relationships, it looks like you only care about the set of characters, rather than the ordering. You can handle this with a character class which just includes those three types of characters.

```
Regex.IsMatch(input, @"^[-0-9.]+$")
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you want "Selective matching", and I do not know the regular expression syntax in C#, but in Perl language. your requirement can be done via:
$some_string =~ /^\d+(-|.)\d+/, you can search more information about "Selective matching" in C#'s regular expression